# React/Redux-Toolkit Cannot read properties of state (undefined)

Tags: state, undefined, redux-toolkit

I am doing a useSelector to get the value of state in Redux Toolkit but get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dasboard')

i tried to look at the Redux Toolkit documentation and compare to my code but still can fix this issue.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-swartz-n0s6s3

Could you please help to let me know the point?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not a higher order function, so you just need to pass it into `useSelector`;

```
const colap = useSelector(colapSlider);
```